# Room error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    java.lang.String matchId);
```

on my `matchedBefore()` query:

```
@Dao
interface MatchedUsersDao {

    // Checks to see if user has matched before (if it returns 1)
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matched_users WHERE :matchId = match_id LIMIT 1")
    fun matchedBefore(matchId: String): Int

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    fun addMatchUid(matchId: String)
}
```

Here is my Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "matched_users")
data class MatchedUser(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "match_id") val matchId: String
)
```

DB

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(MatchedUser::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun matchedUsersDao(): MatchedUsersDao
}
```

and I instantiate my DB in my Application:

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        var database: AppDatabase? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        CustomApplication.database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "AppDatabase").build()
    }
```

Can someone tell me what the error is indicating and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
fun addMatchUid(matchId: String)
```

If you want use `@Insert` annotations you must send instance of `MatchedUser` not String.

So you can :

**1)** Send new `MatchedUser` with your id (insert empty `MatchedUser` with your id)

You code must be like this

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
fun addMatchUid(matchUser: MatchedUser)
```

**2)** Wrote new `@Query` for inserting just id in db